# Why int for integer yet not str for string

Tags: string, integer

I'm not so puzzled as to why int is used for integer, it's shorter that's all. However I don't understand why we don't shorten the string type to str. E.g:

```
int a = 5
str c = "yeah"
```

My questions are:

1. What language first used int instead of integer
2. Why don't we use str to shorten the string type

Comment: Python uses `str` for string.

Comment: Int is the way the type is named in C. I believe "str" was never used for "string" because the concept of "string" was added in later languages (C++, etc). Str is a very common variable name, too.

Comment: @ChristianStewart: C doesn't have a string type. It has strings, but a C string is a data layout, not a data type (defined as "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character").

Comment: Because you can easily pronounce 'int' but not 'str'.

Comment: @Robert That's just a pronunciation issue.  For me it's as simple as 'struct' except without 'uct'. So just str-uct without uct.

Answer (score 1):

I think the usage of int began with ALGOL68 which then influenced C, which influenced Perl, Python, Javascript, Java and of course C++

In ALGOL60 and Fortran you have to write INTEGER.

str for string, is something I only know from Python

Comment: In Algol68 **string** is defined **flex[0]char**... But **string** does stick as a quirk (ignoring **struct**) it could be **str** cf. wp:[Bold symbols & reserved words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68#Bold_symbols_and_reserved_words). A68 can be fixed with declaration **mode str=string** - now 48 years late! A couple of other quirks in A68, eg const _null_character_ should be _null_char_.  Also _long_max_int_ & _long_max_real_ should be called _long_int_max_ & _long_int_max_ resp.  (cf. _long_int_width_). Note that Python continued the fuddle by having: sys.maxint vs sys.float_info.max